# Disable suspend when pressing fn+F4

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, suspend

I have a System 76 laptop with Oneiric. I just tried to turn the volume down using fn+F5 but I accidentally pressed fn+F4 and suspended the system instead. Is there a way to disable that so I won't make the mistake again?

Answer (score 2):

If you look into this directory

```
ls /etc/acpi/events/
```

then there should be somewhere a sleep-button-file. In this file you could disable the action when this event is sent.

Comment: there is indeed /etc/acpi/events/sleepbtn but commenting out suspend action in it has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I could only solve this issue by
1) Editing the file /etc/acpi/sleep.sh (`gksu gedit /etc/acpi/sleep.sh`) and
2) Putting `#` before `pm-suspend`.

[image]

If you are lazy, just paste this on a terminal (a backup will be created):

```
sudo sed -i".bak" 's/pm-suspend/\#pm-suspend/' /etc/acpi/sleep.sh
```